# HttpResponse to String android

Tags: android

I am trying to covert the http response to string using the code below, but my response string is getting terminated in the middle any ideas, how to convert http response to string so that i dont get any buffer problem.

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Anyone any suggestion please help. 
Thanks 
Deepesh

Comment: Hi, Also the problem is buffer cant hold large values so what should be the solution....

Answer (score 112, accepted):

i think, there is a simpler way:

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(resp_entity);
```

right?

Comment: This is a one-line replacement to the convertStreamToString *but* it consumes the buffer! That means that you cannot call it twice (eg in one line for log and in the next in order to do the actual processing). You have to comment the former in order to have the latter.

Comment: @denispyr what you mean? can you explain it ? where did you read that?

Comment: @Nikhil I mean that resp_entity becomes invalid (empty? I cannot recall right now). I didn't read it anywhere, I crashed on it when I logged before the actual processing. Did something change?

Comment: what is `resp_entity` here ?

Answer (score 24):

Get the response InputStream like this:

```
httpResponse = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
```

Try this method:

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I did this...but since my response is large the buffer doesnt hold that, I tried holding it in a string then also it is terminating randaomly... any idea

Comment: hmm, can you modify your web service to split the response? just like pagination, so at first request item 1 - 50, then 51 - 100.

Comment: @ ayublin     I cant do that...since my request is a plist i need the full response in one go, if i break the response the api wont support that. There must some way to store huge strings of data as response right ???

Comment: Are you using JSON? Many people suggest to use Jackson JSON parser [link](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), it can parse JSON directly from url or stream.

Comment: maybe you can use [SAX Parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) and parse your plist response directly from InputStream without converting them into String, sorry I can't help alot, I don't have experience with plist.

Comment: so you have solved your problem? did you ended up using SAXParser?

Comment: the problem was nothing..the logcat doesnt print large strings, the data was always present in the variable.

Comment: @djrecker - I'd love it if that was my problem.  I am receiving an XML error, because an end tag is missing:  error 11-07 17:53:22.794: W/System.err(12266): com.soraco.qlm.QlmLicense$QlmPrivateKeyException: Qlm Private Key Exception in Activate License:  Failed to load the private key: expected: '>' actual: '' (position:END_TAG </QuickL>@1:1309 in java.io.StringReader@43cfa728)

Answer (score 13):

```
HttpResponse response = http.execute(httpMethod);
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
switch(responseCode) {
case 200:
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if(entity != null) {
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    }
    break;
}
```

See http://cdrussell.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/android-get-body-of-http-response-as.html

Answer (score 6):

```
HttpPost httppost;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
        ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();  
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        String bytesSent;

        httppost = new HttpPost(URL OF YOUR SITE);  
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();  

        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", value1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", value2));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key3", value3));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
        bytesSent = httpclient.execute(httppost, res);
```

This is the code of HTTPPOST using this you can get a response in String.

If you have to pass query string to server then you can use `nameValuePairs`

Comment: HI, I have used almost all option i figured out that the problem is my buffer is not able to hold the response and it is not a really big string too...I dont understand y is this happening I have written a iphone app also that doesnt give any problem...

Comment: If your response is very large then you should read input stream directly instead of storing it into string

Comment: @djrecker - Did you ever get this resolved?  I am having same problem on Android but not iPhone.  Same issue as you.  Did you ever figure out what to do to get the entire response for Android?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a more robust way of doing this that handles encoding and gzipped responses, try this:

```
String encoding = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
InputStream stream = AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent(response.getEntity());
InputStreamEntity unzEntity = new InputStreamEntity(stream,-1);
String response = EntityUtils.toString(unzEntity, encoding);
```

Comment: Worked, nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Some one can try this one. I have tested it and its running properly.

```
 public String convertHttpResponseToString(HttpResponse res) {  
    InputStream is=null;   
    String responseString="";  
    try {  
        is=res.getEntity().getContent();  
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));  
        String line="";  
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();  
        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)  
        {  
        sb.append(line);  
        }  
        responseString=sb.toString();  
    } catch (Exception e)  
    {  
          // handle Exception here...
    }  
    return responseString;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String convertHttpResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
InputStream responseStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(responseStream, "UTF-8");
String responseString = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
scanner.close();
return responseString;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

if You have Response Instead of HttpResponse .You can get status code in this way . Thanks

```
 final int statusCode = response.code();
```