# on buttonclicklistener how to write the code of calling .netwebservice

Tags: android, web-services, button

there is a webmethod for insertion,I want to invoke it from the help of interface and button clickevent.How can I do this
                                    Please help me

Comment: Please explain more... Cant understand what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make a `webService`.
and you have to make a script that listen your request and give you a proper response.

If you have a webservice then you can use `HTTPPOST` method and you can upload data through `NameValuePair` and get response from webservice.

You can pass action to server like

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "INSERT"));
```

for information about `HTTPPOST` see the link below

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854243/httpresponse-to-string-android/6854288#6854288
```