# How do I read Distance Matrix API response in JSON from my app?

Tags: android, json, httprequest, google-distancematrix-api

```
     String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+expedTextView.getText().toString()+"&destinations="+destTextView.getText().toString()+"&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyC9BT3f2jmmPSJh2ewGfGiuVz1zeIfPX4A";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(SecondScreen.this, ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

This is my code. I've tried to make an HTTP request suing this URL which constructs just fine, but, when I read the response, it doesn't look like JSON at all. Below is the code from response. Notice that the link works well when I put it in my browser.

```
          HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2019 14:26:57 GMT, Expires: Sat, 12 Jan 2019 14:26:57 GMT, Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400, Server: mafe, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Server-Timing: gfet4t7; dur=91, Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35", Accept-Ranges: none, Vary: Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.BasicManagedEntity@2bffe96
          D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwToast-Toast, themeResId : 0x7f0d0005, context : com.example.rarestaciu.bikemessengerapp.SecondScreen@309bb49, Nhwext : 6, get Blur : disable with , android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable@aadbe04
```

Comment: You have to get the response data out of your HttpResponse object. Try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854280/284308

Comment: thanks! that worked!